# How step definition written in one feature file can be used across all the feature file in BDD

Tags: bdd

Can any one please tell me;how the step definition written in one feature file of BDD framework can be accessed across all the feature files in the project.

Thanks,
Eswar

Comment: You should start by saying which framework, language are you using. step definition file is not necessarily related to a feature file.

Comment: "step definitions" are the automation code for the particular steps, so you don't write them in the feature file, but to code files. In the feature file you have "steps". Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the tool. The general view using Cucumber would be not to do that. That is, do not call steps in other features.

Steps, that is the code that actual is executed, are being reused in Cucumber as long as they found properly. That is where the reuse could happen. Reuse is also expected to happen in the helper methods that steps are delegating to. That is perhaps the most common place to reuse logic used by your BDD framework.

You want to remember that BDD is first and most about communication. It is not about programming or testing. Therefore, duplication in the Gherkin is acceptable as long as communication between the stakeholders, the tester and the developers is clear and concrete.